# Discord Bot | Auto-Role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot give a role when a user joins the server but the event just doesn't work.
It doesn't show any error or anything, it's just don't give a role.

My code:

```
@Client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    intents = discord.Intents().all()
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix, intents=intents)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Unverified')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `ctx` is not defined. Also i fixed your structure.

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
Client= commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@Client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Unverified')
    await member.add_roles(role)

client.run('TOKEN')
```